# get financial year from a date in oracle

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to find out the current financial year (2013-2014) from a date (24/07/2013) in a short way.

I have tried this

```
select extract(year from report_date)||' - '|| 
       extract(year from report_date) + 1 year 
  from bdpr_swtch_yrd
```

and apart from this if I can find out, in which quarter the selected date belongs.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on when the financial year ends?  For example, if the financial year ends June 30 (which is not uncommon), the logic would be different depending on whether the report date is before or after June 30.  For example, if The report date is April 15, 2013, then it should say Financial Year 2012-2013.  But if the report data is October 1, 2013, then it should say Financial Year 2013-2014.

Comment: I mean financial year here as 1st April -31st March.

Comment: Financial quarter or calendar quarter?

Comment: same financial quarter....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is a offset of 3 months, you should subtract 3 months from current date and then extract the year.

```
SELECT    EXTRACT (YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -3))
       || '-'
       || EXTRACT (YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 9))
  FROM DUAL;
```

Output:`2013-2014`

```
SELECT    EXTRACT (YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS (DATE '2013-03-31', -3))
       || '-'
       || EXTRACT (YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS (DATE '2013-03-31', 9))
  FROM DUAL;
```

Output:`2012-2013`

**EDIT:**

To find all records in the financial year, first you need to find the start and end date of the financial year, which is always 1st April and 31st March. There are several ways to get this. I'll continue with the same approach as above, since we already have got the year.

```
Start_date:= to_date('01-04-'||EXTRACT (YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS (reference_date, -3)),'dd-mm-yyyy')
End_date  := to_date('01-04-'||EXTRACT (YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS (reference_date,  9)),'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

So, your where clause should look something like this.

```
select * from table_name
 where column_name between Start_date and End_date;
```

Comment: Dear, is there a way I can find all records which comes in the whole financial year based on a date.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN TO_CHAR (indate, 'MMdd') >  '0331'
             THEN to_char(indate,'yyyy')
          ELSE to_char(to_number(to_char(indate,'yyyy'))-1)
       END AS FY
  FROM DUAL;
```

For other formats:

```
select FY||'-'||(FY+1) as FY,FY||'-'||substr((FY+1),3,2) as FYN from (   
  SELECT CASE
          WHEN TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'MMdd') >  '0331'
             THEN to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')
          ELSE to_char(to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'))-1)
       END AS FY
  FROM DUAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should return the fiscal year based on the current date, given that your fiscal year ends March 31:

```
SELECT
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate) +  DECODE(SIGN(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM') - 3), -1, 0, 1) 
AS FISCAL_YEAR
FROM DUAL
```

This should return the quarter of the current date:

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'Q') 
  FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
It is just returning the next fiscal year (i.e. 2014), but what I wanted was the financial year (i.e 2013-2014) in case a date belongs between 01/04/2013 to 31/03/2014, and similarly for the next...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SYSDATE,CASE 
         WHEN TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MMdd') >  '0331'
         THEN to_char(SYSDATE,'yyyy')||'-'||to_char(to_number(to_char(SYSDATE,'yyyy'))+1)
      ELSE to_char(to_number(to_char(SYSDATE,'yyyy'))-1)||'-'||to_char(SYSDATE,'yyyy')
      -- to_char(to_number(to_char(SYSDATE,'yyyy'))-1)
   END AS FY
FROM DUAL;
```

Try this, Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

For many, the fiscal year begins in october, which puts the offset at +3. Borrowing from the code from Noel:

extract( year from add_months(date '2013-10-15',3))
or
extract( year from add_months(sysdate,3))

This code gives the fiscal year for any given date. you can then use a +1 or -1 year or duplicate the code to do specifically what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

select '01-04'|| '-' || FY AS SFNY , '31-03'|| '-' ||(FY+1) as EFNY from (
SELECT CASE
WHEN TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'MMdd') >  '0331'
THEN to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')
ELSE to_char(to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'))-1)
END AS FY
FROM DUAL);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).